# Error en python IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.7

Tengo este programa que consulta datos en una base de datos y me da error en la:

```
def Editar_producto(self):
```

donde me da este error que seguro es muy basico pero que no hay manera de poder solucionar.

El programa es este:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox 

import sqlite3


class Producto():
    db_name='database_proyecto.db'
    def __init__(self, ventana_producto):
        menubar=Menu(ventana_producto)   
        ventana_producto.title("PAPODATOS")
        ventana_producto.geometry("1400x660")
        ventana_producto.resizable(1,1)
        ventana_producto.config(bd=10,menu=menubar)
        
        "---------------------Menu---------------------------"
        Productos=Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)

        menubar.add_cascade(label="Productos",menu=Productos)

             #Acciones de menu
        self.boton_registrar=Productos.add_command(label="Registrar",command= self.widgets_crud,compound=LEFT)
        self.boton_buscar=Productos.add_command(label="Buscar",command=self.widgets_buscador,compound=LEFT)

        "---------------------Widgets---------------------------"
        #widgets crud
        self.Label_titulo_crud=LabelFrame(ventana_producto)
        self.frame_logo_productos = LabelFrame(ventana_producto)
        self.frame_registro = LabelFrame(ventana_producto, text="Informacion del producto",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold"),pady=5)
        self.frame_botones_registro=LabelFrame(ventana_producto)
        self.frame_tabla_crud=LabelFrame(ventana_producto)
        #widgets buscador
        self.Label_titulo_buscador=LabelFrame(ventana_producto)
        self.frame_buscar_producto = LabelFrame(ventana_producto, text="Buscar producto",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold"),pady=10)
        self.frame_boton_buscar=LabelFrame(ventana_producto)
        #widgets informacion
        self.Label_informacion = LabelFrame(ventana_producto)

        #Pantalla inicial
        self.widgets_crud()

    def widgets_crud(self):
        self.Label_titulo_crud.config(bd=0)
        self.Label_titulo_crud.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        "--------------- Titulo --------------------"
        self.titulo_crud= Label(self.Label_titulo_crud, text="PAPODATOS",fg="black",font=("Comic Sans", 17,"bold"))
        self.titulo_crud.grid(row=0,column=0)
        

        "--------------- Frame marco --------------------"
        self.frame_registro.config(bd=2)
        self.frame_registro.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

        "--------------- Formulario --------------------"
        label_PRODUCT=Label(self.frame_registro,text="PRODUCT: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        self.PRODUCT=Entry(self.frame_registro,width=25)
        self.PRODUCT.focus()
        self.PRODUCT.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=8)
        
        label_SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR=Label(self.frame_registro,text="SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        self.SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR=Entry(self.frame_registro,width=25)
        self.SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=8)
        
        label_HWSWCL=Label(self.frame_registro,text="HW/SW/CL: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=1,column=4,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=9)
        self.HWSWCL=Entry(self.frame_registro, width=22)
        self.HWSWCL.grid(row=1,column=5,padx=5,pady=0)


        label_MANUFACTURER=Label(self.frame_registro,text="MANUFACTURER: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        self.MANUFACTURER=Entry(self.frame_registro,width=25)
        self.MANUFACTURER.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=8)

        label_GMC=Label(self.frame_registro,text="GMC: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=2,column=2,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        self.GMC=Entry(self.frame_registro,width=25)
        self.GMC.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=8)

        label_MANUFACTURERSAPID=Label(self.frame_registro,text="MANUFACTURER SAP ID: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=2,column=4,sticky='s',padx=10,pady=8)
        self.MANUFACTURERSAPID=Entry(self.frame_registro,width=25)
        self.MANUFACTURERSAPID.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=10, pady=8)

        label_TypeofBussiness=Label(self.frame_registro,text="Type of Bussiness: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky='s',padx=10,pady=8)
        self.TypeofBussiness=Entry(self.frame_registro,width=25)
        self.TypeofBussiness.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=8)

        label_PreferredSupplier=Label(self.frame_registro,text="Preferred Supplier: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=3,column=2,sticky='s',padx=10,pady=8)
        self.PreferredSupplier=Entry(self.frame_registro,width=25)
        self.PreferredSupplier.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=10, pady=8)

        label_SAPSupplierID=Label(self.frame_registro,text="SAP Supplier ID: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=3,column=4,sticky='s',padx=10,pady=8)
        self.SAPSupplierID=Entry(self.frame_registro,width=25)
        self.SAPSupplierID.grid(row=3, column=5, padx=10, pady=8)

        label_ContactName=Label(self.frame_registro,text="Contact Name: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=4,column=0,sticky='s',padx=10,pady=8)
        self.ContactName=Entry(self.frame_registro,width=25)
        self.ContactName.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=8)

        label_Role=Label(self.frame_registro,text="Role: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=4,column=2,sticky='s',padx=10,pady=8)
        self.Role=Entry(self.frame_registro,width=25)
        self.Role.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=10, pady=8)

        label_Email=Label(self.frame_registro,text="Email: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=4,column=4,sticky='s',padx=10,pady=8)
        self.Email=Entry(self.frame_registro,width=25)
        self.Email.grid(row=4, column=5, padx=10, pady=8)

        label_Mobile=Label(self.frame_registro,text="Mobile: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=5,column=0,sticky='s',padx=10,pady=8)
        self.Mobile=Entry(self.frame_registro,width=25)
        self.Mobile.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10, pady=8)

        label_OfficePhone=Label(self.frame_registro,text="Office Phone: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=5,column=2,sticky='s',padx=10,pady=8)
        self.OfficePhone=Entry(self.frame_registro,width=25)
        self.OfficePhone.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=10, pady=8)

        label_Comments=Label(self.frame_registro,text="Comments: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=5,column=4,sticky='s',padx=10,pady=8)
        self.Comments=Entry(self.frame_registro,width=25)
        self.Comments.grid(row=5, column=5, padx=10, pady=8)

        
        "--------------- Frame botones --------------------"
        self.frame_botones_registro.config(bd=0)
        self.frame_botones_registro.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

        "--------------- Botones --------------------"
        boton_registrar=Button(self.frame_botones_registro,text="REGISTRAR",command=self.Agregar_producto,height=2,width=12,bg="green",fg="white",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=15)
        boton_editar=Button(self.frame_botones_registro,text="EDITAR",command=self.Editar_producto ,height=2,width=12,bg="gray",fg="white",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=15)
        boton_eliminar=Button(self.frame_botones_registro,text="ELIMINAR",command=self.Eliminar_producto,height=2,width=12,bg="red",fg="white",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=15)
        
        "--------------- Tabla --------------------"
        self.frame_tabla_crud.config(bd=2)
        self.frame_tabla_crud.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

        self.tree=ttk.Treeview(self.frame_tabla_crud,height=11, columns=("columna1","columna2","columna3","columna4","columna5","columna6","columna7","columna8","columna9","columna10","columna11","columna12","columna13","columna14"))
        self.tree.heading("#0",text='PRODUCT', anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("#0", width=80, minwidth=80, stretch=NO)
        
        self.tree.heading("columna1",text='SUPPLIER DISTRIBUTOR', anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("columna1", width=80, minwidth=80, stretch=NO)
        
        self.tree.heading("columna2",text='HW/SW/CL', anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("columna2", width=80, minwidth=80, stretch=NO)
                
        self.tree.heading("columna3",text='MANUFACTURER', anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("columna3", width=80, minwidth=80, stretch=NO)
        
        self.tree.heading("columna4",text='GMC', anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("columna4", width=80, minwidth=80, stretch=NO)

        self.tree.heading("columna5",text='MANUFACTURER SAP ID', anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("columna5", width=80, minwidth=80, stretch=NO)

        self.tree.heading("columna6",text='Type of Bussiness', anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("columna6", width=80, minwidth=80, stretch=NO)

        self.tree.heading("columna7",text='Preferred Supplier', anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("columna7", width=80, minwidth=80, stretch=NO)

        self.tree.heading("columna8",text='SAP Supplier ID', anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("columna8", width=80, minwidth=80, stretch=NO)

        self.tree.heading("columna9",text='Contact Name', anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("columna9", width=80, minwidth=80, stretch=NO)

        self.tree.heading("columna10",text='Role', anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("columna10", width=80, minwidth=80, stretch=NO)

        self.tree.heading("columna11",text='Email', anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("columna11", width=80, minwidth=80, stretch=NO)

        self.tree.heading("columna12",text='Mobile', anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("columna12", width=80, minwidth=80, stretch=NO)

        self.tree.heading("columna13",text='Office Phone', anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("columna13", width=80, minwidth=80, stretch=NO)

        self.tree.heading("columna14",text='Comments', anchor=CENTER)
        self.tree.column("columna14", width=80, minwidth=80, stretch=NO)
        
        self.tree.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=E)
        
        self.Obtener_productos()
        
        #REMOVER OTROS WIDGETS
        self.widgets_buscador_remove()
        self.Label_informacion.grid_remove()

    def widgets_buscador(self):
        self.Label_titulo_buscador.config(bd=0)
        self.Label_titulo_buscador.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

        "--------------- Titulo --------------------"
        self.titulo_buscador= Label(self.Label_titulo_buscador, text="BUSCADOR",fg="black",font=("Comic Sans", 17,"bold"))
        self.titulo_buscador.grid(row=0,column=0)
        
        "--------------- Frame buscar --------------------"
        self.frame_buscar_producto.config(bd=2)
        self.frame_buscar_producto.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        
        "--------------- Formulario Buscar--------------------"
        self.label_buscar=Label(self.frame_buscar_producto,text="Buscar Por: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=5)
        self.combo_buscar=ttk.Combobox(self.frame_buscar_producto,values=["PRODUCT","MANUFACTURER"], width=22,state="readonly")
        self.combo_buscar.current(0)
        self.combo_buscar.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)

        label_PRODUCT_MANUFACTURER=Label(self.frame_buscar_producto,text="PRODUCT/MANUFACTURER: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=5)
        self.PRODUCT_MANUFACTURER=Entry(self.frame_buscar_producto,width=25)
        self.PRODUCT_MANUFACTURER.focus()
        self.PRODUCT_MANUFACTURER.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=5)

        "--------------- Frame marco --------------------"
        self.frame_boton_buscar.config(bd=0)
        self.frame_boton_buscar.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)
        "--------------- Boton --------------------"
        self.boton_buscar=Button(self.frame_boton_buscar,text="BUSCAR",command=self.Buscar_productos,height=2,width=20,bg="black",fg="white",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold"))
        self.boton_buscar.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5)

        self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())

        #REMOVER OTROS WIDGETS
        self.widgets_crud_remove()
        self.Label_informacion.grid_remove()
        
    def widgets_crud_remove(self):
        self.Label_titulo_crud.grid_remove()
        self.frame_registro.grid_remove()
        self.frame_botones_registro.grid_remove()

    def widgets_buscador_remove(self):
        self.Label_titulo_buscador.grid_remove()
        self.frame_buscar_producto.grid_remove()
        self.frame_boton_buscar.grid_remove()

    def widgets_informacion(self):
        self.Label_informacion.config(bd=0)
        self.Label_informacion.grid(row=0,column=0)
        "--------------- Titulo --------------------"
        self.Label_titulo = Label(self.Label_informacion,text="PAPODATOS",fg="white",bg="black",font=("Comic Sans", 25,"bold"),padx=137,pady=20)
        self.Label_titulo.grid(row=0,column=0)


        "--------------- opciones--------------------"
        self.Label_titulo = Label(self.Label_informacion,text="> CONTROL DE PRODUCTOS ",fg="black",font=("Comic Sans", 18,"bold"))
        self.Label_titulo.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W,padx=30,pady=10)

        self.Label_titulo = Label(self.Label_informacion,text="> BUSCADOR DE PRODUCTOS ",fg="black",font=("Comic Sans", 18,"bold"))
        self.Label_titulo.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W,padx=30,pady=10)



        #Remove
        self.widgets_buscador_remove()
        self.widgets_crud_remove()

    "--------------- CRUD --------------------"               
    def Obtener_productos(self):
        records=self.tree.get_children()
        for element in records:
            self.tree.delete(element)
        query='SELECT * FROM Productos ORDER BY MANUFACTURER desc'
        db_rows=self.Ejecutar_consulta(query)
        for row in db_rows:
            self.tree.insert("",0, text=row[1],values=(row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[9],row[10],row[11],row[12],row[13],row[14],row[15]))
            
    def Agregar_producto(self):
        if self.Validar_formulario_completo() and self.Validar_registrar():
            query='INSERT INTO Productos VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
            parameters = (self.PRODUCT.get(),self.SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR.get(),self.HWSWCL.get(),self.MANUFACTURER.get(),self.GMC.get(),self.MANUFACTURERSAPID.get(),self.TypeofBussiness.get(),self.PreferredSupplier.get(),self.SAPSupplierID.get(),self.ContactName.get(),self.Role.get(),self.Email.get(),self.Mobile.get(),self.OfficePhone.get(),self.Comments.get())
            self.Ejecutar_consulta(query, parameters)
            messagebox.showinfo("REGISTRO EXITOSO", f'Producto registrado: {self.PRODUCT.get()}')
            print('REGISTRADO')
            self.Limpiar_formulario()
        self.Obtener_productos()
    
    def Eliminar_producto(self):
        try:
            self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            messagebox.showerror("ERROR","Porfavor selecciona un elemento") 
            return
        dato=self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR=self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][1]
        query="DELETE FROM Productos WHERE PRODUCT = ?"
        respuesta=messagebox.askquestion("ADVERTENCIA",f"¿Seguro que desea eliminar el producto: {Producto}?")
        if respuesta == 'yes':
            self.Ejecutar_consulta(query,(dato,))
            self.Obtener_productos()
            messagebox.showinfo('EXITO',f'Producto eliminado: {Producto}')
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('ERROR',f'Error al eliminar el producto: {Producto}')
     
    def Editar_producto(self):
        try:
            self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            messagebox.showerror("ERROR","Porfavor selecciona un elemento") 
            return
        PRODUCT = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][1]
        SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][2]
        HWSWCL = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][3]
        MANUFACTURER = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][4]
        GMC = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][5]
        MANUFACTURERSAPID = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][6]
        TypeofBussiness = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][7]
        PreferredSupplier = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][8]
        SAPSupplierID = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][9]
        ContactName = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][10]
        Role = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][11]
        Email = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][12]
        Mobile = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][13]
        OfficePhone = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][14]
        Comments=self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][15]
        
        self.Ventana_editar = Toplevel()
        self.Ventana_editar.title('EDITAR PRODUCTO')
        self.Ventana_editar.resizable(0,0)
        
        
        #Valores ventana editar

        label_PRODUCT=Label(self.Ventana_editar,text="PRODUCT: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        nuevo_PRODUCT=Entry(self.Ventana_editar,textvariable=StringVar(self.Ventana_editar,value=PRODUCT),width=25)
        nuevo_PRODUCT.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=8)

        label_SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR=Label(self.Ventana_editar,text="SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        nuevo_SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR=Entry(self.Ventana_editar,textvariable=StringVar(self.Ventana_editar,value=SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR),width=25)
        nuevo_SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=8)
    
        label_HWSWCL=Label(self.Ventana_editar,text="HWSWCL: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=9)
        nuevo_HWSWCL=Entry(self.Ventana_editar,textvariable=StringVar(self.Ventana_editar,value=HWSWCL),width=25)
        nuevo_HWSWCL.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=5,pady=0)

        label_MANUFACTURER=Label(self.Ventana_editar,text="MANUFACTURER: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        nueva_MANUFACTURER=Entry(self.Ventana_editar,textvariable=StringVar(self.Ventana_editar,value=MANUFACTURER),width=25)
        nueva_MANUFACTURER.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=5, pady=8)

        label_GMC=Label(self.Ventana_editar,text="GMC: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=2,column=2,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        nuevo_GMC=Entry(self.Ventana_editar,textvariable=StringVar(self.Ventana_editar,value=GMC),width=25)
        nuevo_GMC.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=5, pady=8)

        label_MANUFACTURERSAPID=Label(self.Ventana_editar,text="MANUFACTURERSAPID: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=2,column=4,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        nuevo_MANUFACTURERSAPID=Entry(self.Ventana_editar,textvariable=StringVar(self.Ventana_editar,value=MANUFACTURERSAPID),width=25)
        nuevo_MANUFACTURERSAPID.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=5, pady=8)

        label_TypeofBussiness=Label(self.Ventana_editar,text="TypeofBussiness: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=1,column=4,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        nuevo_TypeofBussiness=Entry(self.Ventana_editar,textvariable=StringVar(self.Ventana_editar,value=TypeofBussiness),width=25)
        nuevo_TypeofBussiness.grid(row=2, column=5, padx=5, pady=8)

        label_PreferredSupplier=Label(self.Ventana_editar,text="PreferredSupplier: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=3,column=4,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        nuevo_PreferredSupplier=Entry(self.Ventana_editar,textvariable=StringVar(self.Ventana_editar,value=PreferredSupplier),width=25)
        nuevo_PreferredSupplier.grid(row=3, column=5, padx=5, pady=8)

        label_SAPSupplierID=Label(self.Ventana_editar,text="SAPSupplierID: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=4,column=0,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        nuevo_SAPSupplierID=Entry(self.Ventana_editar,textvariable=StringVar(self.Ventana_editar,value=SAPSupplierID),width=25)
        nuevo_SAPSupplierID.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=8)

        label_ContactName=Label(self.Ventana_editar,text="ContactName: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=4,column=2,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        nuevo_ContactName=Entry(self.Ventana_editar,textvariable=StringVar(self.Ventana_editar,value=ContactName),width=25)
        nuevo_ContactName.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=5, pady=8)

        label_Role=Label(self.Ventana_editar,text="Role: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=4,column=4,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        nuevo_Role=Entry(self.Ventana_editar,textvariable=StringVar(self.Ventana_editar,value=Role),width=25)
        nuevo_Role.grid(row=4, column=5, padx=5, pady=8)

        label_Email=Label(self.Ventana_editar,text="Email: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=5,column=0,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        nuevo_Email=Entry(self.Ventana_editar,textvariable=StringVar(self.Ventana_editar,value=Email),width=25)
        nuevo_Email.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=8)

        label_Mobile=Label(self.Ventana_editar,text="Mobile: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=5,column=2,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        nuevo_Mobile=Entry(self.Ventana_editar,textvariable=StringVar(self.Ventana_editar,value=Mobile),width=25)
        nuevo_Mobile.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=5, pady=8)

        label_OfficePhone=Label(self.Ventana_editar,text="OfficePhone: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=3,column=2,sticky='s',padx=5,pady=8)
        nuevo_OfficePhone=Entry(self.Ventana_editar,textvariable=StringVar(self.Ventana_editar,value=OfficePhone),width=25)
        nuevo_OfficePhone.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=5, pady=8)
        
        label_Comments=Label(self.Ventana_editar,text="Comments: ",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold")).grid(row=5,column=4,sticky='s',padx=10,pady=8)
        nueva_Comments=Entry(self.Ventana_editar,textvariable=StringVar(self.Ventana_editar,value=Comments),width=25)
        nueva_Comments.grid(row=5, column=5, padx=10, pady=8)

        boton_actualizar=Button(self.Ventana_editar,text="ACTUALIZAR",command= lambda: self.Actualizar(nuevo_PRODUCT.get(),nuevo_SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR.get(),nuevo_HWSWCL.get(),nueva_MANUFACTURER.get(),nuevo_GMC.get(),nuevo_MANUFACTURERSAPID.get(),nuevo_TypeofBussiness.get(),nuevo_PreferredSupplier.get(),nuevo_SAPSupplierID.get(),nuevo_ContactName.get(),nuevo_Role.get(),nuevo_Email.get(),nuevo_Mobile.get(),nuevo_OfficePhone.get(),nueva_Comments.get(),PRODUCT,MANUFACTURER),height=2,width=20,bg="black",fg="white",font=("Comic Sans", 10,"bold"))
        boton_actualizar.grid(row=3, column=1,columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=15)
        
        self.Ventana_editar.mainloop()      
        
    def Actualizar(self,nuevo_PRODUCT,nuevo_SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR,nuevo_HWSWCL,nueva_MANUFACTURER,nuevo_GMC,nuevo_MANUFACTURERSAPID,nuevo_TypeofBussiness,nuevo_PreferredSupplier,nuevo_SAPSupplierID,nuevo_ContactName,nuevo_Role,nuevo_Email,nuevo_Mobile,nuevo_OfficePhone,nueva_Comments,PRODUCT,SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR):
        query='UPDATE Productos SET PRODUCT = ?, SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR = ?, HWSWCL = ?, MANUFACTURER =?, GMC=?, MANUFACTURERSAPID=?,TypeofBussiness=?,PreferredSupplier=?,SAPSupplierID=?,ContactName=?,Role=?,Email=?,Mobile=?,OfficePhone=?,Comments =? WHERE PRODUCT = ? AND SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR =?'
        parameters=(nuevo_PRODUCT,nuevo_SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR,nuevo_HWSWCL,nueva_MANUFACTURER,nuevo_GMC,nuevo_MANUFACTURERSAPID,nuevo_TypeofBussiness,nuevo_PreferredSupplier,nuevo_SAPSupplierID,nuevo_ContactName,nuevo_Role,nuevo_Email,nuevo_Mobile,nuevo_OfficePhone,nueva_Comments,PRODUCT,SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR)
        self.Ejecutar_consulta(query,parameters)
        messagebox.showinfo('EXITO',f'Producto actualizado:{nuevo_SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR}')
        self.Ventana_editar.destroy()
        self.Obtener_productos()

    def Buscar_productos(self):
        #Obtener todos los elementos con get_children(), que retorna una tupla de ID.
        records=self.tree.get_children()
        for element in records:
            self.tree.delete(element)
        
        if (self.combo_buscar.get()=='PRODUCT'):
            query=("SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE PRODUCT LIKE ? ") 
            parameters=(self.PRODUCT_MANUFACTURER.get()+"%")
            db_rows=self.Ejecutar_consulta(query,(parameters,))
            for row in db_rows:
                self.tree.insert("",0, text=row[1],values=(row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[9],row[10],row[11],row[12],row[13],row[14]))
            if(list(self.tree.get_children())==[]):
               messagebox.showerror("ERROR","Producto no encontrado")
        else:
            query=("SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE MANUFACTURER LIKE ? ")
            parameters=("%"+self.PRODUCT_MANUFACTURER.get()+"%")
            db_rows=self.Ejecutar_consulta(query,(parameters,))
            for row in db_rows:
                self.tree.insert("",0, text=row[1],values=(row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[9],row[10],row[11],row[12],row[13],row[14]))
            if(list(self.tree.get_children())==[]):
               messagebox.showerror("ERROR","Producto no encontrado")

    "--------------- OTRAS FUNCIONES --------------------"
    def Ejecutar_consulta(self, query, parameters=()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conexion:
            cursor=conexion.cursor()
            result=cursor.execute(query,parameters)
            conexion.commit()
        return result   
          
    def Validar_formulario_completo(self):
        if len(self.PRODUCT.get()) !=0 and len(self.SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR.get()) !=0 and len(self.HWSWCL.get()) !=0 and len(self.MANUFACTURER.get()) !=0 and len(self.GMC.get())  !=0 and len(self.MANUFACTURERSAPID.get())!=0 and len(self.TypeofBussiness.get())!=0 and len(self.PreferredSupplier.get())!=0 and len(self.SAPSupplierID.get())!=0 and len(self.ContactName.get())!=0 and len(self.Role.get())!=0 and len(self.Email.get())!=0 and len(self.Mobile.get())!=0 and len(self.OfficePhone.get()) !=0 and len(self.Comments.get()):
            return True
        else:
             messagebox.showerror("ERROR", "Complete todos los campos del formulario") 
    
    def Limpiar_formulario(self):
        self.PRODUCT.delete(0, END)
        self.SUPPLIERDISTRIBUTOR.delete(0, END)
        self.HWSWCL.delete(0, END)
        self.MANUFACTURER.delete(0, END)
        self.GMC.delete(0, END)
        self.MANUFACTURERSAPID.delete(0, END)
        self.TypeofBussiness.delete(0, END)
        self.PreferredSupplier.delete(0, END)
        self.SAPSupplierID.delete(0, END)
        self.ContactName.delete(0, END)
        self.Role.delete(0, END)
        self.Email.delete(0, END)
        self.Mobile.delete(0, END)
        self.OfficePhone.delete(0, END)
        self.Comments.delete(0, END)

    def Validar_registrar(self):
        parameters= self.PRODUCT.get()
        query="SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE PRODUCT = ?"
        dato = self.Ejecutar_consulta(query,(parameters,))
        if (dato.fetchall() == []):
            return True
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("ERROR EN REGISTRO", "PRODUCT registrado anteriormente")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ventana_producto=Tk()
    label_crud=Label(ventana_producto)
    application=Producto(ventana_producto)
    ventana_producto.mainloop()
```

y el error que me da es este:

```
error line 310, in Editar_producto
    OfficePhone = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][14]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Entiendo que este error sugiere que la lista en `values` no tiene un elemento en la posición 13. Esto podría deberse a que los valores que estás tratando de acceder no están presentes en la posición esperada o que la lista `values` es más corta de lo que estás asumiendo, pero no hay manera de encontrar la solución, ¿me podeis echar un cable?

Mil gracias.

Comment: ¿Python 2 o 3? Ya sabés cuál es el problema, entonces ¿por qué seguís intentando obtener el valor en esa posición?

Comment: Y por cierto, no pongas _help, aiudaaa_ o similares en la pregunta. Por otra parte, dale el formato correcto a tu código, agregando triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después del código. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: el problema es que no se como solucionar el problema exactamente y me gustaria que me ayudasen en ello.

Comment: Te hice una pregunta trampa, leela de vuelta porque estoy tratando de decirte algo: si ya te diste cuenta que devuelve un error cuando intentás acceder a esa posición, ¿por qué seguís intentando obtener el valor allí? Recordá siempre, siempre, depurar el código: ¿qué pasa cuando borrás posiciones? ¿y cuando las agregás? ¿qué comportamiento distinto hay en el código, y en la base de datos?

Comment: Y de nuevo: ¿Python 2 o 3? ¡Eliminá la etiqueta que no corresponda!

Comment: Métele un try-except IndexError y maneja el error en función de los datos que tengas